# Python string: how to replace only some numbers?

Tags: python, regex

I was practicing some regex using re module. I wonder how 
can we change only some numbers from the string.

```
a1 = 'images1/b100.png'

# required:
a2 = 'images2/b100.png'
```

My attempt:

```
import re
a1 = 'images1/b100.png'
nums = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', a1)))
num0 = nums[0]
a2 = a1.replace(str(num0), str(num0+1))
```

Comment: Which number do you want to specifically change. Yes I know you want to change the `1` to `2`, but which number do you want to change _generally_? Is it to always change the first digit to a `2`? Or add one to the first number? Or change the first number that's before a `/` to a `2`? It also would be great if you could show more examples of inputs and your desired output.

Comment: @Sweeper only the first number found in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide an argument to only replace the first occurence.

Change:

```
a2 = a1.replace(str(num0), str(num0+1))
```

To:

```
a2 = a1.replace(str(num0), str(num0+1), 1)
```

As mentioned here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

> str.replace(old, new[, count])
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

Answer (score 1):

you could type:

```
a2 = a1.replace(str(num0), str(num0+1), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the Answer,

```
a2.replace("b200","100")
```

Result:
'images2/100.png'

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a1 = 'images1/b100.png'
matches = re.match( r'^(.*)(\d+)(\/.*)$', a1)
a2 = matches.group(1)+str(int(matches.group(2))+1)+matches.group(3)
```

`^(.*)(\d+)(\/.*)$`: A path ending with a digit and any filename.

Comment: For `'images1/folder100/hello1.png'`  required is `'images2/folder100/hello2.png'`  This answer gives different result.